# npm start can't access by localhost

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I built react project by

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Now I run

```
npm start
```

below is the output

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view todos in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000/
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.31.146:3000/

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.
```

I can access my project by http://192.168.31.146:3000/,
but I can't access by  http://localhost:3000/

If I change localhost to 127.0.0.1, it's ok.

My question is how can I access my project by  http://localhost:3000/

Comment: sorry, I have three Q: 1.Does 127.0.0.1:3000 work? 2.What operating system are you running? 3.try different browsers?

Comment: you need to add `localhost   127.0.0.1` in hosts file

Answer (score -2):

ReInstall node.js and restart my computer, everything is ok!
sorry